# Ordering WP_Query by 'meta_value_num' while also using 'offset'

Tags: wordpress

I have a WP_Query like so:

```
    <?php $args = array(
    'post_type'=> array('post', 'page'),
    'cat'=> 108,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'offset' => 4,
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => '3 months ago'
        )
    ),
);
query_posts( $args ); ?>
```

What I want is are 10 posts that:

1. Have the highest value for `post_views_count`
2. Are *not* the 4 most recent posts published.

But it seems that `'offset' => 4` is running the query, ordering by `post_views_count` and then skipping 4 of those, instead of the most recently published 4.

Would anyone have any insight into how I can it to skip the first 4 and *then* run my meta_key query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get somewhere earlier 4 first published posts you must put their ids in array and use query arg

```
'post__not_in' => $exclude_posts_arr
```

instead of

```
'offset' => 4,
```

If you didn't get this post earlier you can create another query with this parameters.

Comment: You're welcome, mark answer as accepted please.